# ASP.net forms authentication - admin kill a single user's session

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

A slightly odd question came through to us.  Is there way to programatically cause a single user to be 'logged out' when logged in as another user (e.g. as an administrator).

e.g. An admin on stackoverflow would decide that I should be logged out - click a button and then I would be forced to log in again on my next SO request.

This is for a site using standard forms based authentication running ASP.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the authenticated sessions depend on the cookie, they don't know about each other.

So you need to track the logged in users may be along with their roles.  And perform a check at the beginning of every request.

You start by tracking:

1. user A - role 'admin' logs in. Create a row in db
2. user A - role 'manager' logs in, now you mark the row in step 1 as expired, and create a new row for user A - role 'manager'
3. user A - role 'admin' attempts to perform some action.  In the begin request method, you will verify if this session is marked for expiration.  If it is simply logout, remove the row in step 1 and redirect to login.
4. user A clicks logout, remove user A - role 'manager' row

Comment: I was thinking that we would need something like this, bit of a nuisance, but there you go.  Thanks for the input.